# 775twins hdtv motherboard doesnt have Ethernet drivers for win 7

Tags: drivers, motherboard, lan

I have 775twins hdtv motherboard but in the manufacturer site there are only drivers for windows xp, and my computer is missing the Ethernet drivers what can I do

Answer (score 0):

There are no official Windows 7 drivers for that ethernet chipset.  There are some 3rd party drivers you can find out on the internet, but I avoid those like the plague.  Your best bet would be to buy a new ethernet card.  Ethernet cards are cheap and you can get one that is guaranteed to work with Windows 7 and 8.

Comment: do you think drivers for vista will work on win 7? because right now I am unable to buy new ethernet card. I searched the internet and I couldnt find any drivers for my motherboard above windows xp

Comment: Its *possible* that the drivers will work, but no guarantee.  You say its not possible to buy one, but any computer store would have them.  Or you can order online from your phone...

Comment: Worst case you can **try** the win XP 64 bits drivers from [europe.asrock.com/drivers/ATi/LAN/LAN_XP64_XP_2K_ME_98(3.50).zip](ftp://europe.asrock.com/drivers/ATi/LAN/LAN_XP64_XP_2K_ME_98(3.50).zip). (XP 64 is closer to server 2003 light than to XP), and someone mentioned success on this site: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprohardware/thread/d01fb594-440d-4bd6-8d9d-b4ea2b515bd4

Comment: @Hennes I downloaded the driver that you suggested and it works great thank you